# How can I split a string then edit the string then place back the delimiters to their original spot

Tags: java, regex, string, split, apache-pig

I am working on a Pig Latin project which requires to change any sentence input by the user to be translated into Pig Latin. I have the conversion down and it works. However I have issues with punctuation. When I split my string to work on each individual word in the string the punctuation gets in the way. I would like to know a way to be able to split the string input into its individual words however keep the delimiters and then be able to properly place back the punctuation and whitespaces?

Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word or phrase: ");
    String convert = scanner.nextLine();
    String punctuations = ".,?!;";
    //convert = convert.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", ""); //idk if this is useful for me 
    String finalSentence = "";
    if (convert.contains(" ")) {
        String[] arr = convert.split("[ ,?!;:.]+");
        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
                if (vowel(arr[index]) == true) {
                    System.out.println(arr[index] + "yay");
                    finalSentence = (finalSentence + arr[index] + "yay ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(newConvert(arr[index]));
                    finalSentence = (finalSentence + newConvert(arr[index]) + " ");
                }

        }
```

Comment: This is largely a problem of what sort of structure you want to use to represent the parsed sentence.

Comment: Well, your problem here is that you have a list of words attained by splitting some larger string, but those words have punctuation in them. You could solve this problem by deleting all punctuation, but then you have no way to get it back at the end. So you need a way to represent *all* the information from the original string in a data structure that is easier to use than a simple string.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to all of this. So what sort of data structure would I use  rather than a string?

Comment: That's the thing: it depends very heavily on exactly what operations you need to perform on your data.

Comment: So would separating it into chars work better for example?

Comment: You mean like a `char[]`? That's pretty much exactly the same as a `String`.

Comment: I'm not really sure what sort of data structure to use then?

Comment: Could you show me an example of a StringBuilder and how to append. I haven't learned how to use those yet

Comment: I don't think that will really help with the problem at hand, but there's a good StringBuilder tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) if you're interested.

Comment: ok thank you. I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String convert = "The quick? brown!!fox jumps__over the lazy333 dog.";
    StringBuilder finalSentence = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> tokens = Arrays.asList(convert.split(""));
    Iterator<String> it = tokens.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      String token = it.next();
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      while (token.matches("[A-Za-z]")) {
        sb.append(token);
        if (it.hasNext()) {
          token = it.next();
        } else {
          token = "";
          break;
        }
      }
      String word = sb.toString();
      if (!word.isEmpty()) {
        finalSentence.append(magic(word));
      }
      finalSentence.append(token);
    }
    //prints "The1 quick1? brown1!!fox1 jumps1__over1 the1 lazy1333 dog1."
    System.out.println(finalSentence.toString());
  }

  private static String magic(String word) {
    return word + 1;
  }
```

Do the Pig Latin translation in the `magic` method.

Answer (score 0):

I defined two methods for the Pig Latin translation: the **convert_word_to_pig_latin** method is to convert each word into Pig Latin, and the **convert_sentence_to_pig_latin** method is for a sentence using the convert_word_to_pig_latin method.

```
def convert_word_to_pig_latin(word)
  vowels = "aeiou"
  punctuations = ".,?!'\":;-"

  if vowels.include?(word[0])
    return word
  else
    if punctuations.include?(word[-1])
      punctuation = word[-1]
      word = word.chop
    end
      first_vowel_index = word.chars.find_index { |letter| vowels.include?(letter) }
      new_word = word[first_vowel_index..-1] + word[0...first_vowel_index] + "ay"
      return punctuation ? new_word += punctuation : new_word
  end
end



def convert_sentence_to_pig_latin(sentence)
  sentence_array = sentence.split(" ")
  sentence_array.map { |word| convert_word_to_pig_latin(word) }.join(" ")
end
```

**NOTE:** Please feel free to add any additional punctuation marks as you'd like.

Lastly, here is my RSpec to ensure both of my methods pass all tests:

```
require_relative('../pig_latin')

describe 'Converting single words to Pig Latin' do
  word1 = "beautiful"
  word2 = "easy"
  word3 = "straight"

  it "converts word to Pig Latin" do
    expect(convert_word_to_pig_latin(word1)).to eq "eautifulbay"
  end

  it "does not change word if it begins with a vowel" do
    expect(convert_word_to_pig_latin(word2)).to eq "easy"
  end

  it "converts word to Pig Latin" do
    expect(convert_word_to_pig_latin(word3)).to eq "aightstray"
  end
end

describe 'Converting a sentence to Pig Latin' do
  sentence1 = "Make your life a masterpiece; imagine no limitations on what you can be, have, or do."
  sentence2 = "The pessimist sees difficulty in every opportunity. The optimist sees the opportunity in every difficulty."

  it "converts motivational quote from Brian Tracy to Pig Latin" do
    expect(convert_sentence_to_pig_latin(sentence1)).to eq "akeMay ouryay ifelay a asterpiecemay; imagine onay imitationslay on atwhay ouyay ancay ebay, avehay, or oday."
  end

  it "converts motivational quote from Winston Churchill to Pig Latin" do
    expect(convert_sentence_to_pig_latin(sentence2)).to eq "eThay essimistpay eessay ifficultyday in every opportunity. eThay optimist eessay ethay opportunity in every ifficultyday."
  end
end
```